# How to split a matrix into 4 submatrixes using javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, split

I have a matrix like this...

```
const AMatrix = 
[
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [5,6,7,8]
]
```

And I want to split it into 4 submatrices like this

```
[
    [1,2],
    [1,2]
]
[
    [3,4],
    [3,4]
]
[
    [5,6],
    [5,6]
]
[
    [7,8],
    [7,8]
]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: No Actually. I want it to Halve Every Even Length Matrix Vertically and Horizontally and create 4 Sub Matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```js
const AMatrix =
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [5, 6, 7, 8]
    ];
const res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < AMatrix.length; i += 2) {
    res.push([AMatrix[i].slice(0, 2), AMatrix[i + 1].slice(0, 2)]);
    res.push([AMatrix[i].slice(2), AMatrix[i + 1].slice(2)]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: thank you. is it possible to make it dynamic to work for every even length matrices?

Comment: you mean matrices sizes 4x4, 6x6, 8x8 or 4x4, 8x8, 16x16 ?

Comment: there was an "or" in my question

Answer (score 0):

```js
const AMatrix = 
[
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [5,6,7,8]
]

const result = []
for(let i=0; i<AMatrix.length; i+=2){
    result.push([ [AMatrix[i][0], AMatrix[i][1]], [AMatrix[i+1][0], AMatrix[i+1][1]] ]);
    result.push([ [AMatrix[i][2], AMatrix[i][3]], [AMatrix[i+1][2], AMatrix[i+1][3]] ]);
}

[m1, m2, m3, m4] = result;

console.log(m1)
console.log(m2)
console.log(m3)
console.log(m4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic approach

```js
const AMatrix = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16], [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16] ]
res=[]
function chuncks(n){
  let i=0
  while(i<AMatrix.length){
    for(let j=0;j<AMatrix[i].length;j++){
      res.push([AMatrix[i].splice(0,n),AMatrix[i+1].splice(0,n)])
      res.push([AMatrix[i].splice(0,n),AMatrix[i+1].splice(0,n)])
      j--
    }
    i+=2
  }
}
chuncks(2)
console.log(res)
```